# Visual Studio can't start the project

Tags: visual-studio

I have problem in run my project in Visual Studio.

When I start the project, everything is Ok.

Build succeeds without any error, but suddenly the project stopped without any reason.

And in my output I have:

```
The program '[7368] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
The program '[7368] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6260] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6260] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have multiple dotnet installations? Installing the latest version may help. Switching to command line may give you better insight.

Comment: @MohitJain Thanks I will try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actiolly you have to update your visual-studio, If doesent work you have to check your connection to your source control, because may when want to start, ckeck gou connection

Finally if don't, get again resouce from source controll.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don’t like to answer my question.
But I resolved this.

If you use of tfs source control, when you want to get latest of project, may in meny reason, get latest will work not correctly.

Because of this issue, your project wil not start or start and stop suddy.

Get latest again, your project.